# Кличний відмінок слів „кравець“, „швець“

Tags: відмінювання, кличний-відмінок

Яка форма кличного відмінка правильна: *кравче* чи *кравцю*, *шевче* чи *шевцю*? От *хлопець* — *хлопче*, але *гінець* — *гінцю*, чи не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Беру відомости з [українського мовно-інформаційного фонду НАН України](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/LSlist/).

Коли [кравець](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C), то **кра́вче**. Але коли прізвище: **Кравцю́** чи **Краве́ць**.

Те саме з [швець](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D1%88%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C): **ше́вче**, але для прізвища — **Шве́цю** чи **Швець**.

З [хлопець](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C) — *хло́пче*, [гінець](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C) — *гінцю́* все так.